# Regex: Match permutations with repetitive chars whereby one char can not occur more than once

Tags: java, regex, permutation, restriction

The regex should match all strings, which are between 2 and 3 chars long and contain only A and B ([AB]{2,3}). But also it should just match strings, which contain a maximum of one B.

Allowed strings:

> AA
>   AB
>   BA
>   AAA
>   AAB
>   ABA
>   BAA

Not allowed:

> ABB <-- two B's

Is it possible to achieve this with a single regex? I tried something like that:

> ([AB]{2,3})(?<=([B]*A[B]*){2})

But it's not working in Java because it does not support a variable length for the Look-behind group.

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 28
>   ([AB]{2,3})(?<=([B]*A[B]*){2})

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a negative lookahead to ensure that the string does not have two `B`s.

```
^(?!.*B.*B)[AB]{2,3}$
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/99133LyaIx)

Comment: That's is exactly what I searched for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can just list the options individually:

```
^(A{2,3}|A{1,2}B|ABA|BA{1,2})$
  ↑      ↑       ↑   ↑
  │      │       │   └─ starting with B
  │      │       └───── B in the middle
  │      └───────────── B at the end
  └──────────────────── only A
```

Comment: It's in the »B at the end« option. Same as in your regex, actually.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
\b(?:A{1,2}B|BA{1,2}|A{2,3}|ABA?)\b
```